# I am trying to remove the # sign from the url in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-router

i am using PathLocationStrategy  and add following code

```
imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // remove second argument
]
```

but has is removed from the url but when refresh the page the following error occur

> page not found

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the hash, you start to use `HTML5` routing mechanism. To use this you need to configure the *web server* to support `HTML5` routing mechanism on which you have hosted your website. The configuration is different per web servers.

Comment: Or, redirect all the HTML5 routing to `index.html` to let angular handle the routing

Comment: Yes, configuring the server also does this actually

Answer (score 0):

you could set the webserver default to your index.html

**nginx**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;


    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

**apache2**

create a .htaccess file with this content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```